# Accessing Hardware PKCS11 Token on a 64 Bit Machine

Tags: java, certificate, 32bit-64bit, pkcs#11

So here's what I'm trying to do. I have a hardware token with some certs on it and I'm writing a Java application to try and access those certs. I have used the SunPKCS11 library in jre6 for a windows 32 bit machine. This is a small sample of how I access the certs:

```
String configName = "pkcs.cnf"
String PIN = "123456";
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
Security.addProvider(p);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
char[] pin = PIN.toCharArray();
keyStore.load(null, pin);
```

It works great, I'm able to get the certs and everything. Now I'm trying to do the same on a 64 bit machine. However I am trying to use the 64 bit jre6 library and that is missing the SunPKCS11 jar file `(located in {java.home}/lib/ext`. Because of that I cannot create a SunPKCS11 object. My question to you is, what do I do now? How can I access the certs on a token using 64 bit java libraries? Has someone written a 64 bit wrapper for such a task?

Comment: Is there a good reason to use java 64 bit version? Because if you are using Microsoft Windows 64 bits with java 32 bit version, Sun PKCS #11 will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PKCS11 Support was not implemented because there was no way to test that library (somehow, whatever).

This has changed in Java 8, though. Since J8b49 a 64 bit Version is included.
See:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6880559

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your {java.home} points to jre6, sunpkcs11.jar is in the {java.home}/lib/ext;
If your {java.home} points to jdk1.6, sunpkcs11.jar is in the {java.home}/jre/lib/ext;
I've tested it against the newly installed jdk and jre.
Please verify your installation.

**EDITED** (summarising the comments)
In java 64-bit version pkcs11 is not available.

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit machine? It is not there under the 64 bit installation of java. That is the problem I am having.

Comment: Yes, you're right.
I tested it in my 64 bit server with jdk-6u22-windows-i586.exe which is 32 bit installation.
SUNPKCS11 is not implemented in 64 installation of WINDOWS JDK.

Comment: There is not much of a performance gain on 64 bit Java, is it a possability to wait for the PKCS#11 provider to be compiled? Or do you need 64 bit memory space for your application? If the need is very dire, you could compile OpenJDK in 64 bit and test if you get the PKCS#11 provider to work. This will take quite a bit of knowledge and (for a Windows compile) patience getting the required libraries and tools.