# 64 bit alternative to SunPkcs11 implementation

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#11

We use a middle-ware to build software applications which is installed over JDK 1.6.30 64 bit setup.

We recently got a requirement to sign certain requests using USB token. I googled around and found out that an implementation is provided by Sun in the name of SunPKCS11. But, the same is only available in 32 bit JRE until Java 8.

I want to know if there are any alternative non commercial implementations available out there which I can make use of.

Please note that upgrading Java or changing the architecture is not an option as there is a high dependency on the middleware.

Comment: Hi Pavan, unfortunately "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Check out the Software Recommendations site: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please don't build security related software on deprecated platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Its not available for jdk 1.6 (applicable for windows only) but available for Java 8 64bit. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615068/2115983) for more details

Refer this link where it says:

> The Sun PKCS#11 provider is supported on Solaris (SPARC and x86) and Linux (x86) in both 32-bit and 64-bit Java processes. It is also supported on 32-bit Windows (x86) but not currently on 64-bit Windows platforms due to the lack of suitable PKCS#11 libraries.

[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html)

Comment: Hi vishnu, as I mentioned in the post. Upgrading java is not an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from some research that the [IAIK wrapper for PKCS#11](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core-Crypto-Toolkits/PKCS_11_Wrapper) is also compatible with 64 bit. You could use this to sign, but IAIK does not provide a JCE compatible provider for free. This means that you can use it for direct calls to the PKCS#11 library underneath, but you would loose all compatibility with the standard Java functionality build around the JCE. The Sun and IAIK PKCS#11 *providers* are build on top of this free library.

Comment: I've used this IAIK wrapper for interfacing to an HSM, it worked very well and was easy to port.

Comment: Hi @EJP, I've used it as well, but just on 32 bit. I understand you had to compile the native part for 64 bit? It's been a while since I last used it...

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why...

Comment: No, I had to compile the native part for an IBM platform actually. Did it on a site visit to IBM in about half an hour.

Comment: Yes I looked into the IAIK library. But as you mentioned, this isn't free to use for transformations. But I have to do both signing and decryption. Im surprised how nobody else ran into this. :-)

Comment: The wrapper lib *is free* (after registration). That's the answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead I'm sorry I didn't get you. Can I use the wrapper library for performing transformations (decryption mostly) as well?

Comment: @Pavan Absolutely, it's just not a library that implements the provider interface that JCE/JCA uses. That means that any software that relies on JCA also doesn't work.

Comment: I mean: basically it is a rather direct conversion from Java to PKCS#11. Expect all the PKCS#11 functionality - encryption, decryption, hashing, key agreement etc. etc. in a embarrassingly non-object oriented wrapper lib.